# Recieving SQL Syntax error on simple insert query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I have some simple 4 field SQL-Query with Parameters to insert a single record into some logging-table in ms-access database.

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO logHistory (ip, action, userid, time)" +
      "VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @time)";
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new new OleDbCommand(SQL, intranetDB))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", ip);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", action);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", userID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", 
        OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DateTime.Parse(time);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

table structure is quite simple:

```
CREATE TABLE logHistory{
   id int auto_increment Primary Key,
   ip varchar(15),
   action varchar(50),
   userid int,
   time datetime
}
```

Unfortunately i get SQL-Syntax error when executing above code.
As for the values i try to insert:

> ip = any IPv4 address, that might get generated...
>   action = "SomeTestingString"
>   userid = any integer < 999
>   time = DateTime.Now;

i have tried parsing the time beforehand in some different manners and i am running out of ideas.

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss");
string time = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `Unfortunately i get SQL-Syntax error when executing above code.` What does it say?

Comment: 'Syntax Error in INSERT INTO-Statment'. this is catched by C# runtime to sql-Exception and i can't get deeper information :(,

Details: Microsoft JET Database Engine at Logger ln.55 (which is cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();)

Comment: not sure but maybe a space is missing in the first line:
`string SQL = "INSERT INTO logHistory (ip, action, userid, time) " +`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is an MS Access database then the word TIME is a reserved keyword. You need to use square brackets around it to use in a query. Looking better, also the word ACTION is reserved.....

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO logHistory (ip, [action], userid, [time])" +
                  "VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3, @time)";
```

If it is possible, I strongly suggest to change these names because you will have this problem everytime you hit this table.

[List of reserved keywords for JET.4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266)

Instead in Access 2007 the word ACTION is no more listed between the reserved ones.....

[List of reserved keywords for Access 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)